# ionic 5 : TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, observable, angular8, ionic5

I have this service in IONIC 5 :

---

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
.
.
.
getPlaces(placeId: string) {
return this.httpClient.get(
        `https://test.com/offered-place/${placeId}.json`)
}
.
.
.
```

---

In my component when i  try to call may service's function and subscribe to it:

---

```
this.myService.getPlaces().subscribe(()=>{})...
```

I got the error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined.

---

but when I try to subscribe within the service it works !!

ps:

- IONIC 5

my service is injected in the constructor of my component (where I got my error)

my service is annotated :

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

- IDE Visual Code

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the component it won't work because the getPlaces function requires placeID and from the component you are not sending the value to the function when you are calling

```
this.myService.getPlaces().subscribe(()=>{})...
```

so you have to pass placeID in this and subscribe it by adding a reference like i have written result. Now in result you will have the data from the api.

```
this.myService.getPlaces(placeID should be passed here).subscribe((result)=>{console.log(result);})...
```

and in the service add Observale to the function

```
getPlaces(placeId: string): Observable<any> {
return this.httpClient.get(
        `https://test.com/offered-place/${placeId}.json`)
}
```

Comment: For the Id params i had it i just forgot to put it here, in the other hand  aded "Observable<any>", ans i had a new error "A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.", i think this.httpClient.get(..) return a void (or at least this is what it thinks)

Comment: can you share the service that you created again? also in the component did you initialize the service in the constructor? 

constructor(private myService: ServiceClassName) ?

Because the service you created should be declared in the app.module inside the providers array